# Is it correct and natural to say "get one's life set" meaning to become successful and financially secure?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Is it correct and natural to say *get one's life set* meaning to become successful and financially secure? For example:

> Not that you **got your life set**, have you thought of going on a round-the-world trip?

Would also be possible to say *get one's love life* set meaning to have a steady girlfriend or boyfriend? If not, what would you say for both?

Comment: That's understandable. It would work better as "you've got your life set". A common idiom in English is "set for life" (see in Wiktionary).

Comment: Thanks, for the comment! What about "love life"?

Comment: It's a little business-like for referring to one's affectionate life, as if it's something to  be arranged and gotten out of the way. But, if that's the way one looks at it, it works.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you would say about arranging one's affectionate life?

Comment: That's the problem right there! Do you "arrange your love life", or do you fall in love with someone? The latter is something that happens, more than something you do. And after you have your affectionate life "set", what if she decides she likes someone else better? Maybe it wasn't quite so "set" after all.

Comment: I mean "arrange your love life" like getting a steady girlfiend or wife. What would you say in this case?

Comment: I would not say that, that's my point. I wouldn't think of arranging my love life.